# Linearization of a dynamic system, $\small 10 \frac{d^2 y}{dt^2} + \frac{d y}{dt} = u^2(t) $

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-optimization

I have a dynamic system, with in signal u and out signal y. The system is described with the following differential equation

$$
10 \frac{d^2 y}{dt^2} + \frac{d y}{dt} = u^2(t)
$$

The task is to linearize around u=1.

I would like to know how it is done, step by step.

Comment: Please, avoid double dollar symbols in titles. Since the eqn was still forcing the title to line-break, I added a `\small`.

Comment: Oh, I just wondered why it made such a clumsy title..

Comment: @Mikael The way you've written it, isn't this a perfectly reasonable nonhomogeneous linear ODE in $y$? I mean, if you really want to approximate the right hand side by something linear in $u$, which I presume is given, then since the Taylor series of $f(x) = x^2$ about $x=1$ is $f(x) = 1 + 2(x-1) + (x-1)^2$, the "linearisation" of the right hand side is $1+2(u(t)-1) = 2u(t)-1$.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić pretty much the answer.